# Правильные конструкторы в javascript

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Есть какой-нибудь конструктор.

```
var Animal = function (data) {
  this.name = data.name;
  this.age = data.age;
  this.kind = data.kind;
}
```

Надо произвести валидацию входных данных. То есть убедится, что `typeof name === String`, `typeof age === 'number'` и `1+['cat', 'dog', 'mongoose'].indexOf(kind)`. Как это проверить очевидно. Вопрос в том, где проверять. Прямо в конструкторе? Или так:

```
var validate = function () {
  if (typeof this.name !== 'string') throw new Error;
  if (typeof this.age !== 'number') throw new Error;
  if (-1 === ['cat', 'dog', 'mongoose'].indexOf(kind)) throw new Error;
},
Animal = function (data) {
  this.name = data.name;
  this.age = data.age;
  this.kind = data.kind;
  validate.call(this);
}
```

Как это вообще делать правильно?

@eicto,

> разница в моем и вашем коде ещё и такая - я сначала валидирую, а потом провожу инициализацию

```
Animal = function (data) {
    validate.call(this);
    this.name = data.name;
    this.age = data.age;
    this.kind = data.kind;
}
```

Тот факт, что валидация происходит в конструкторе уже считается признаком гавнокода?

@Etki,

> Но если вы не стремитесь писать идеальный код сразу же - ну эээ это печально.

Ну с чего бы я вообще подымал бы этот вопрос, если бы не стремился писать нормальный код изначально))?

Comment: Валидацию надо делать до попадания данных в конструктор

Comment: @MasterAlex с чего бы ? Т.е. почему-это валидацией данных для объекта, должен заниматься какой-то другой объект ?

Comment: @alvoro сделайте например метод 

    Animal.prototype.validate=function(data) {
     return //сам объект или false если валидацию не прошло. 
    } 

вызывайте метод из конструктора,

мое в общем мнение такое - объект сам должен заботиться о своих данных, снаружи его нужно использовать, согласно спецификации интерфейса.

Comment: Итог, если я не ничего не недопонял - валидации в конструкторе не место. Валидируем до попадания данных в конструктор. Кто будет валидировать определяем по ситуации. Спасибо @MasterAlex и @eicto.

Comment: нет, не до попадания данных, а до попадания данных на обработку конструктору, вызывать валидатор - из конструктора, но это должен быть метод самого объекта, еще (мб даже луче) сделать это не методом объекта а функцией в стиле

    var Animal=(function() {
      function validate(data){}
      var Animal=function(data) {
       validate(data);
      }
      return Animal;
    }());


тогда можно не светить метод валидации наружу.

Comment: @alvoro: Задайте себе вопрос: почему кто-то кроме самого объекта должен знать и быть ответственным за данные, с которыми может работать объект? Почему объект должен доверять данным, проверенным кем-то ещё? Что будет, если представления проверяющего и самого объекта рассогласуются? Откуда объект может знать, что входные данные проверены — он должен доверять любому, кто вызывает конструктор?

Comment: @eicto, ну тогда это тоже самое, что я предполагал изначально.

    var validate = function () {
      if (typeof this.name !== 'string') throw new Error;
      if (typeof this.age !== 'number') throw new Error;
      if (-1 === ['cat', 'dog', 'mongoose'].indexOf(kind)) throw new Error;
    },
    Animal = function (data) {
      this.name = data.name;
      this.age = data.age;
      this.kind = data.kind;
      validate.call(this);
    }

Вся эта благодать в отдельном модуле. Я снова что то не так понял?

Comment: @alvoro

> Я снова что то не так понял?

Да, у @eicto функция валидации существует внутри декларации оюъекта и не видна снаружи.

Comment: @Etki, я ж указал, что

> Вся эта благодать в отдельном модуле.
В чем разница?

Comment: @alvoro, в том что класс уже не существует без каких-то внешних зависимостей и его интерфейс, пусть и в модуле, размазывается.

Comment: @Etki, это элементы теоретично-идеального кода, или, при использовании javascript, это действительно имеет значение?

Comment: это элементы oop :) разница в моем и вашем коде ещё и такая - я сначала валидирую, а потом провожу инициализацию, ведь обычно init это не только

    this.property=value

но и часто 

    this.methodSet(value);

у меня validate() это статическая функция в понимании функциональных языков, сама она не меняет состояние системы, просто возвращает результат.

Comment: @alvoro, нет никакого идеального кода. Есть код, при написании которого учитывается возможный рефакторинг и нет. 

Вообще конкретно на этот вопрос нет однозначного ответа до появления деталей реализации, может там валидация сама имеет зависимости или должна быть выполнена задолго до создания объекта. Но если вы не стремитесь писать идеальный код сразу же - ну эээ это печально.

Comment: @eicto, @Etki, @VladD, я правильно понимаю вас, что для того чтобы сделать валидацию введённых в форму пользователем данных вы будете делать вызов с созданием объекта? Например, animal[index]  = new Animal(data). Вместо того, чтобы передать данные в функцию animalValidate(data) и по результатам проверки уже создавать объект.

Comment: @MasterAlex: насчёт меня — да. Я, однако, не js-джедай, так что моё мнение основывается на общих принципах ООП.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы писать валидирущий код сразу, не задумываясь, но следуя неким правилам, лучше использовать `TypeScript` или [flow](https://flowtype.org/). По сути вашего вопроса: не так существенно, где проверять в первый раз, однако разумно делать функцию `this.valid()`, чтобы в любой момент узнать статус инстанса, а это бывает полезнее, чем бросать исключения. Но если задумка такова:

```
var Animal = function (data) {
  if(data === null || typeof data !== 'object') throw new Error;
  this.name = data.name;
  this.age = data.age;
  this.kind = data.kind;
  this.validate();
};

Animal.prototype.validate = function () {
  if (typeof this.name !== 'string') throw new Error;
  if (typeof this.age !== 'number') throw new Error;
  if (-1 === ['cat', 'dog', 'mongoose'].indexOf(kind)) throw new Error;
};
```

Comment: только назвал бы её `valid()` и не бросал в ней же исключение, а возвращал булево, обрабатывая ошибку в отдельном цикле.

Comment: В общем случае надо валидировать не состояние объекта `this`, а корректность входных параметров (`data`). Например, ваш подход не будет работать, если конструктор ожидает, что `data.name` это объект со свойствами `givenName` и `familyName`. Если в `data` забудут выставить поле `name`, конструктор упадет на строчке `this.givenName = data.name.givenName`, еще до вызова `vailidate()`.

Comment: в целом да, действительно, особенно если стоит задача именно валидация входных параметров, а не самого объекта (с чем однако я встречаюсь на практике чаще), однако вы не правы в том, что упадёт конструктор в отсутствии `name`, ибо это саовершенно штатная ситуация. Другое дело - обращение к свойству несуществующего объекта, а для обработки этого кейса надо сделать `if(data === null || typeof data !== 'object') threw new Error`
проверка на null нужна, т.к. в js  `typeof null === 'object'`

Comment: пардон, незаметил, что вы подразумеваете именно `name` - это объект, тогда всё верно, но опять же, именно этот факт в этом случае и надо валидировать сперва